# OneDrive: "We can't sign you in" - Cannot resolve with cryptic error about browser cookies

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, onedrive, office365

Seeing an odd issue on a workstation's OneDrive installation. Getting the following error after attempting to enter the email for login:
[image: OneDrive error]

As you can see, it suggest that the browser is set to block cookies, however which browser would OneDrive be talking about?

Edge and Internet Explorer are BOTH set to accept all (1st party and 3rd party) cookies.  I've also cleaned cookies from them.

What could be going on here?  OneDrive is a self contained app it would seem so this kind of a message doesn't really make sense in the first place...

Comment: Are you using a proxy or firewall (other than Windows Firewall)?

Comment: None, no @Ramhound.

Comment: What are you installing exactly, OneDrive, doesn’t have to be installed on Windows 10.  Can you logged into your MS within Edge/IE11?  Edit your question

Comment: Does the issue happen when installing instead of using OneDrive?
Where did you get the OneDrive and how did you install it?

Comment: The error occurred with the default installation of OneDrive in Windows 10. I then uninstalled it and reinstalled it. I received the same error. So... That was just a test to see if it would reset something, such as the cookie storage...

Comment: Are you using the one drive from the Windows store? If so, I would try using the desktop version. Windows store "apps" are way too limited. Here's the link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=248256

Comment: Got it from here: https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/

Comment: Set IE as your default browser on Windows. Then logon OneDrive web page with your Microsoft Account (https://onedrive.live.com/) in IE. Confirm if there is any cookie issue.

Comment: @WinniL that was a great call. This solved it. I'm surprised that Windows 10 still apparently uses the IE cache / session store (cookies) for things such as a supposedly independent application like OneDrive. Remarkable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WinniL [explained](https://superuser.com/questions/1301781/onedrive-we-cant-sign-you-in-cannot-resolve-with-cryptic-error-about-brows/1302273#comment1932978_1301781) in a comment, the solution (while surprising) proposed actually worked:

1. Set Internet Explorer as the default browser (Default app settings
   -> Web browser -> Internet Explorer)
2. Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Privacy (tab) -> Settings
   (header): Sites (button) -> Managed websites (header): Remove All
   (button). Then OK and close out of all these.
3. Visit onedrive.live.com and login here.
4. Now retry the OneDrive app in the System Tray, et voila!